# How to query a sum of every week for the last four weeks in postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

briefly, I have a table of transactions looking like this
[image]

I was trying to query this table by last 7days(`day by day`), last 4weeks(`week by week`), and last 12months(`month by month`).

I was going to get the dates with javascript, query transaction by transaction then do the sum of every (week, day, month) outside then create an array to hold the values. but my guts is telling me it is possible to get most of that with a postgres db query.

so my question is, is it possible if yes how to.

this is me trying to get dates

```
const today = new Date();
const firstWeekEnd = new Date(today);
const secondWeekStart = new Date(today);
const secondWeekEnd = new Date(today);
const thirdWeekStart = new Date(today);
const thirdWeekEnd = new Date(today);
const fourthWeekStart = new Date(today);
const fourthWeekEnd = new Date(today);

function formatDate(date) {
  let dd = date.getDate();
  let mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) { dd = `0${dd}`; }
  if (mm < 10) { mm = `0${mm}`; }
  date = `${yyyy} ${mm}= ${dd}`;
  return date;
}

firstWeekEnd.setDate(firstWeekEnd.getDate() - 6);
secondWeekStart.setDate(secondWeekStart.getDate() - 7);
secondWeekEnd.setDate(secondWeekEnd.getDate() - 13);
thirdWeekStart.setDate(thirdWeekStart.getDate() - 14);
thirdWeekEnd.setDate(thirdWeekEnd.getDate() - 20);
fourthWeekStart.setDate(fourthWeekStart.getDate() - 21);
fourthWeekEnd.setDate(fourthWeekEnd.getDate() - 27);
```

I am using nodejs and sequelize

Any help or thought is highly appreciated

Comment: What is the result you are trying to get?  Are you trying to perform some aggregation?

Comment: yeah, if it's the last seven days, I want the last daily totals( every day total transactions) if you get what I mean @Jeremy so that's seven totals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a CTE which generates a name and a time stamp with time zone range ( [tstzrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) ). Then join that CTE to your table with the [element contained by operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE). Finally, use the SUM function for those falling into particular ranges. See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=95992aca1a993db96ca4efaa515e0b50).

```
with date_ranges (range_name, range_dates) as
     ( values ('week_0', tstzrange ((now()-interval '6 days'),  now(),'[]'))
            , ('week_1', tstzrange ((now()-interval '13 days'), (now()-interval '7 days'), '[]'))
            , ('week_2', tstzrange ((now()-interval '20 days'), (now()-interval '14 days'),'[]'))
            , ('week_3', tstzrange ((now()-interval '27 days'), (now()-interval '21 days'),'[]')) 
     ) 
select range_name, range_dates, sum(amount) total_amount 
  from mytable      mt
  join date_ranges  dr
    on (mt.created_at <@ range_dates)
 group by range_name, range_dates
 order by range_name;
```

Comment: this actually works, a small fix though, the dates are coming with the heavy timestamp precision like timezones and all that, can you help limit that to `yyyy-mm-dd` because it is cutting off some records even tho its on the same date, thanks alot tho for what I have so far +1

Comment: I got it here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813222/how-to-get-dates-with-postgres/63813814#63813814)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a certain function in PostgreSQL that helps you to group data then I have a positive answer for you `date_trunc('week', createdAt )`. It returns the first day of week by which you can group your data like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', createdAt ) as start_of_week, sum(transactionTotal)
FROM <your_table_name_here>
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', createdAt )
ORDER BY date_trunc('week', createdAt )
```

As of Sequelize.js you should use a raw query to execute such SQL-query.

Comment: having some issues with this, first I am trying to have the sum of one week from today not a monday, second I dont need or the possible `weeks` just the last four, `days` last 7, `months` last 12, also some dates seemed to duplicate. Apologies in advance my sql knowledge is low

Comment: I indicated simple SQL-query. You can easily add WHERE clause where you can indicate desired date range like `WHERE createdAt >= '<your_start_date_here>'`

Comment: cool, how do I stop the weeks from starting from monday and start on whatever day you are on though

Comment: Can you show a little example of what you can achieve?